# Python package recognized in Pycharm, not in terminal

Tags: python, django, package, django-imagekit

I'm developing a Django project which imports django-imagekit; everything works fine on my Windows machine.  On my Linux-Ubuntu laptop though, Pycharm recognizes the package in the editor, it's listed in the project's interpreter's packages but it's not recognized from the command line:

```
    simon@Simon-Swanky:~/PycharmProjects/tcspt$ python manage.py check
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 353, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 327, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/home/simon/PycharmProjects/tcspt/assetmanage/models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from imagekit.models import ProcessedImageField
ImportError: No module named imagekit.models
```

It seems to be looking in python 2's packages but I'm using python 3 for this project.  I tried a few things like adding the path to the project variables but so far I can't get it to work.

Trying to import imagekit from python 2's shell:

```
Python 2.7.11+ (default, Apr 17 2016, 14:00:29) 
[GCC 5.3.1 20160413] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import imagekit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named imagekit
```

Trying to import imagekit from python 3's shell:

```
>>> import imagekit
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/imagekit/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import conf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/imagekit/conf.py", line 5, in <module>
    class ImageKitConf(AppConf):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/appconf/base.py", line 74, in __new__
    new_class._configure()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/appconf/base.py", line 100, in _configure
    value = getattr(obj._meta.holder, prefixed_name, default_value)
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/simon/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting IMAGEKIT_DEFAULT_CACHEFILE_BACKEND, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

Comment: Check you are using the appropriate python SDK. You must ensure that pycharm and the terminal run the same python environment when running your script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Python 3, then you should be using `python3 manage.py check`. It might be better to use a virtual environment, in which case you would activate the virtual environment before running `python manage.py check`.

The import fails in the Python 3 shell because you have not set the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` environment variable (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/settings/#designating-the-settings) for more info). The easiest fix is to use the Django shell, which takes care of this for you.

```
$ python3 manage.py shell
>>> import imagekit
```

Comment: Using python3 worked, thank you very much!  I'll check into the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE.